# Scroll down crashes application on a UITableView with a custom UITableViewCell because of zombie object

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios5, automatic-ref-counting

I have this code:

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"BSTGListCell";

    BSTGListCell *cell = (BSTGListCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"BSTGListCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    PFObject* currentEl = [self.tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.title.text = [currentEl objectForKey:@"Name"];
    cell.description.text = [currentEl objectForKey:@"Address"];
    return cell;
}
```

I am getting "message sent to deallocated instance" when scrolling down the table view which is added as a subview.
Zombie inspector says the accessed object is retained here:

```
cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"BSTGListCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
```

and probably released by ARC.
Why this happens and how I can prevent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really shouldn't do it this way. The way to use cell from a nib is to register the nib, probably in viewDidLoad, like this:

```
UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"BSTGListCell" bundle:nil];
[self.tableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"BSTGListCell"];
```

Then in your cellForRowAtIndexPath, use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath: and no if(cell == nil) clause.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    BSTGListCell *cell = (BSTGListCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"BSTGListCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    PFObject* currentEl = [self.tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.title.text = [currentEl objectForKey:@"Name"];
    cell.description.text = [currentEl objectForKey:@"Address"];
    return cell;
}
```

The actual problem with your code is that loadNibNamed:owner:options, returns an array, and you have to get the one object out of that array before you assign it to cell. But, the way I showed is a more efficient way to do this anyway.

Comment: It wasn't exactly the fix I used but very close one.

Comment: @Octavian, what fix did you use?

Comment: Please add your solution for others who are facing the same problem!

Answer (score 0):

My problem was something with the `dequeueReusableCell` line, i took it out [like this link did](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/iphonesdkdevelopment/Ln5qYKT8cl8) and mine works now